# Retrieve datalab_name from nested Json string

Tags: json, groovy, nested

I have a json response that I want to parse via Groovy so as to reteive the all values associated with the the datalab_name attribute. (See responseData2)

I would apprecaite a sample of groovy code that would allow me to retrieve all of the datalab_name values.

A sample of the code that I was using was

**Example Response Data**

```
def restResponse1 = '[{"uid":10512213, "name":"Bob"},{"uid":7208201, "name":"John"},{"uid":10570, "name":"Jim"},{"uid":1799657, "name":"Sally"}]'

def restResponse2 = '[{"beta": {"datalab_name": "beta","allowed_publication_projects": ["ands-datalake-self-service"],"allowed_publication_departments": ["bisdni"]}},{"alpha": {"datalab_name": "alpha","allowed_publication_projects": ["ands-datalake-self-service"],"allowed_publication_departments": ["bisdni"]}}]*'
        
        // Parse the response
        def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText( restResponse1 )
        
        // Print them out to make sure
        list.each { println "CP100  " + it }
        def vMyVar= list.datalab_name
        vMyVar.each { println "CP200  " + it }

        Null is the output that I get. I want to see beta and alpha
```

**Console Output**

```
CP100  [beta:[allowed_publication_departments:[bisdni], allowed_publication_projects:[ands-datalake-self-service], datalab_name:beta]]
CP100  [alpha:[allowed_publication_departments:[bisdni], allowed_publication_projects:[ands-datalake-self-service], datalab_name:alpha]]
CP200  null  // This is wrong null should be replaced with beta
CP200  null  // This is wrong null should be replaced with alpha
```

If I change the JsonSlurper to parse restResponse1 and the code line `def vMyVar = list.name`, then I get the correct name details from restResponse1.

I need help in getting the values associated with the datalab_name

Thanks in advance for any contributions
Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  This should be
something along the lines of `data.collectMany{
it.values()*.datalab_name }`

Comment: The code that I was using was